# Relaxation of linear constraints?

Tags: optimization

When we need to optimize a function on the positive real half-line, and we only have non-constraints optimization routines, we use `y = exp(x)`, or `y = x^2` to map to the real line and still optimize on the log or the (signed) square root of the variable.

Can we do something similar for linear constraints, of the form `Ax = b` where, for x a d-dimensional vector, `A` is a `(N,n)`-shaped matrix and `b` is a vector of length `N`, defining the constraints ?

Comment: No, but bounds are essentially free in linear programming (and many nlp) solvers.

Comment: yeah these are not bounds, but linear constraints. Why 'No' ? Could you justify it ?

Comment: The only thing I know of is substituting variables out ( and eliminating the corresponding constraints) and of barriers/penalties in the objective. Often not a good idea, especially when there are good solvers around that can handle linear constraints.

Comment: If this was a really good idea, solvers would not need to support constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While, as Ervin Kalvelaglan says this is not always a good idea, here is one way to do it.
Suppose we take the SVD of A, getting

```
A = U*S*V'
where if A is n x m
U is nxn orthogonal,
S is nxm, zero off the main diagonal, 
V is mxm orthogonal
```

Computing the SVD is not a trivial computation.

We first zero out the elements of S which we think are non-zero just due to noise -- which can be a slightly delicate thing to do.

Then we can find one solution x~ to

```
A*x = b
```

as

```
x~ = V*pinv(S)*U'*b
```

(where pinv(S) is the pseudo inverse of S, ie replace the non zero elements of the diagonal by their multiplicative inverses)

Note that x~ is a least squares solution to the constraints, so we need to check that it is close enough to being a real solution, ie that Ax~ is close enough to b -- another somewhat delicate thing. If x~ doesn't satisfy the constraints closely enough you should give up: if the constraints have no solution neither does the optimisation.

Any other solution to the constraints can be written
x = x~ + sum c[i]*V[i]
where the V[i] are the columns of V corresponding to entries of S that are (now) zero. Here the c[i] are arbitrary constants. So we can change variables to using the c[] in the optimisation, and the constraints will be automatically satisfied. However this change of variables could be somewhat irksome!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution, which i'm finaly using a few months later. I do have a followup question about adding an inequality constraint there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215982/relaxation-of-equality-and-inequality-linear-constraints